# openVPN and multiple external IP addresses

Tags: linux, vpn, ip, iptables, openvpn

I currently have an openVPN server with multiple external IP addresses.

I'd like to have all VPN connections (tun0 interface, and/or 10.19.88.xx IP range) to take the 2nd external IP address as 'public IP', instead of the first one.

As an example, using fictive addresses:

```
Deault eth0 address: 11.12.13.1 (server.domain.tld)
eth0:0 address: 11.12.13.2 (vpn.domain.tld)
```

All VPN connections are currently using 11.12.13.1, instead of 11.12.13.2.

Is there any way to solve this (using iptables?)

Thanks

Comment: The server is running Debian linux (and is a virtual machine). This server is being used for testing purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.88.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 11.12.13.2
```

Or even better ;)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.88.0/24 -j SNAT --to 11.12.13.2
```

Comment: -o eth0:0 doesn't seem to be working. Only full interfaces are supported (eth0).

Warning: weird character in interface `eth0:0' (No aliases, :, ! or *).

Comment: Fixed my answer :)

Comment: Still not working. '-i' doesn't work with postrouting, and -o eth0 (which I already tried before ;)) still uses the 1st IP address. Thanks

Comment: Just drop the `-i tun0` then.  That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun0 -j SNAT --to 11.12.13.2`

The issue with rkthkr's response (besides the weird character in interface) is that it would only match packets coming in from the 10.19.88.0/24 subnet that are ALREADY going out eth0:0 and SNAT'ing them.

By using `-i tun0`, you're identifying packets only by what interface they come in (I assume that's the only traffic coming in from tun0), and then SNAT'ing it to the proper outgoing IP.

Comment: I concur fully..

Comment: iptables v1.4.2: Can't use -i with POSTROUTING :)

Comment: And leaving out -i doesn't seem to change the VPN external IP address used -- but doesn't output any errors. Not to forget, all other services still need to use 11.12.13.1 as 'main' IP.

Comment: Yeah, leaving out the -i would make everything SNAT to .2.  The second iptables line in rkthkr's answer should work.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't change anything. No errors, but my external IP is still the 11.12.13.1 instead of the 11.12.13.2. I'm guessing iptable is instant, and each change doesn't require the VPN-service to restart or something? I can paste you my sample iptables config if that would be of any help.

Comment: Yeah, lets see your `iptables -t nat -L -v -n` output.  Let's see what it's actually doing.

Comment: I actually had a MASQUERADE rule aswell in it, removing that one solved the problem. Thanks all

Comment: For iptables, order is everything.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

same problems,
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun0 -j SNAT --to 11.12.13.2
not wotking on debian 5

Comment: Make sure there is no other MASQUERADING rule in iptables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "-i interface_name" with POSTROUTING.

-i interface_name --> PREROUTING  (from where a packet comes)

-o interface_name --> POSTROUTING  (to where a packet goes)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use openvpn options instead of bringing-in iptables?

> local 11.12.13.2
>
> bind

Comment: That doesn't (or didn't) work at that time.