# OpenVPN Access Server connects and can browse all other ports than port HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn

Hello dear Serverfault experts,

I have a very frustrating issue with my recently installed OpenVPN Access Server (https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw/113.html?osfamily=CentOS CentOS 6.5)

Everything works, except I can't browse port 80 or port 443.

I can do NSLOOKUP, traceroutes, pings, visit websites that use other ports in the address bar (For instance www.example.com:2087), Skype connects just fine, and so forth. The only thing that doesn't work, is when I want to browse a website on regular port, like www.google.com.

The OpenVPN server is installed on a node hosted by OVH in Canada. It has multiple IPs (Public IPs), 1 Canadian IP and 2 US. It's currently setup to listen and serve on one of the US IPs. I have tried the Canadian IP as well, same result.

Let me know what more information you'd require and I'll reply as quick as possible.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

> Here is the result of the Telnet using Putty:
>   puu.sh/bvMON/2ce15e6735.png 2) This should determine if we are using
>   IPv4 or IPv6, right? puu.sh/bvMSf/1241ddf1c4.png
>   puu.sh/bvMUU/13fa10c86f.png Both internet connection of client and
>   server use IPv4 to connect to each other in the OpenVPN client
>   settings as well. *- Added from comment*

**EDIT 2:**

Server is CentOS 6.5 and client is Windows.

**EDIT 3:**

Here is a "netstat -n" command used while VPN is turned on: http://pastebin.com/iet3ErVX
Please note the "<--- comments"

Kind regards,
Thomas Schmidt

Comment: Is there a proxy configured somewhere? Can you connect using telnet? Is IPv6 complicating things perhaps?

Comment: Hello Wurtel, thank you for your reply. 1) No proxy service is running as far as I'm concerned. 2) What would you like me to telnet to? With VPN on or off? As mentioned, everything works, except browsing websites on port 80 and 443. 3) IPv6 is not configured in the "ifcfg-eth0:0" which is the interface that the OpenVPN Access Server is configured to listen to.

I'm suspecting IPTables of some sort? OpenVPN Access Server automatically inputs rules into IPTables.

Comment: telnet serverfault.com 80, for example, with the VPN on. Then type GET / HTTP/1.0 and enter twice, you should get a HTTP/1.1 302 Found response.  Re: IPv6: if openvpn is only forwarding IPv4 traffic, perhaps your local system also has IPv6 connectivity and hence IPv6 hosts (notably google) will be tried over IPv6 and hence not go through the openvpn pipe.

Comment: 1) Here is the result of the Telnet using Putty: http://puu.sh/bvMON/2ce15e6735.png 2) This should determine if we are using IPv4 or IPv6, right? http://puu.sh/bvMSf/1241ddf1c4.png http://puu.sh/bvMUU/13fa10c86f.png Both internet connection of client and server use IPv4 to connect to each other in the OpenVPN client settings as well.

Comment: Ah, you're using windows... telnet from the linux command line will show what IP address it's connecting to and whether the connection succeeded or not. I'm afraid I'm not qualified enough to troubleshoot your problems on windows. Perhaps netstat -n while you're trying to connect to a webserver in your browser will show what actual connections are being tried.

Comment: The server is CentOS, but the client is Windows. I will try the "netstat -n" command...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iet3ErVX

Comment: traceroute to one of the google IPs **does** work? Then it looks like ports 80 and 443 are explicitly being blocked somewhere :-( If telnet www.google.com 80 works on the openvpn server, then a workaround might be installing squid on your openvpn server and specifying that in your windows browser (use the openvpn internal IP  as the proxy). Installing squid is also not quite straightforward, although if you got openvpn server running then you should be able to handle it. Although I'm curious what's blocking 80/443, any firewall rules on the openvpn server? iptables -L -vn

Comment: Traceroutes: http://puu.sh/bvSc4/3fbec25d33.png
iptables -L -vn: http://pastebin.com/XmzDaFGk

I hope this helps! Thank you again.

Comment: Please also the output of "iptables -t nat -L -vn" and "iptables -t mangle -L -vn", iptables is matching marks which are set somewhere that I don't see yet.

Comment: I found the guilty lines! http://pastebin.com/msaaSVQW such a stupid mistake... I used this for another service a while back.

Comment: I have another minor issue now though. I can I type it here or should I post another question? My server has 3 public IPs and everything in OpenVPN is set to the US IP, which is also the IP I'm connecting to when esthablishing connection. But when I go to www.whatismyipaddress.com I get the Canadian IP shown. Can this be fixed with something like this: http://serverfault.com/questions/71310/openvpn-and-multiple-external-ip-addresses

Comment: ServerFault is a Q&A website, not a forum. Consider posting your solution as an answer and removing the "(Solved)" from the title. After a day you'll be able to accept your own answer as valid.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**

I had these in my iptables:

```
# COMMENTED OUT TO SUPPORT OPENVPN
#-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8880
#-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8881
```